# What is the sum of this series given the closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

The closed form of a series I am trying to identify is:
$$
a_n=\frac{250}{2n -1}
$$

How could I get the sum of the series equation from this? I am used to geometric sequences and arithmetic sequences and this one is confusing me.

Comment: There is no known closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{250}{2k-1}$. You can express it in terms of the closely related $H_m$ (the harmonic numbers). But there is no known closed form for the $H_m$.  Or maybe you mean that the **sum** $s_n$ is $\frac{250}{2n-1}$ and you want to identify the $n$-h summand. That can be done.

Comment: @AndréNicolas It seems to me that the OP is equating the general term of a series with its closed form. Perhaps I misinterpreted.

Comment: @amWhy: As is all too often the case, I do not know what OP intends. I have noticed in the past that you are very good at reconstructing intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean that the *general term* of the series is $a_n = \dfrac{250}{2n - 1}$, then the corresponding *series*  IS the sum of the terms $a_i, \;1\leq a_i$ as $i\to \infty$. That is, the corresponding series is:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{250}{2n-1}$$

This *series* is divergent; as $n \to \infty$, the cumulative sum blows up (is unbounded).

We can, however, compute a sum given some $n$: $S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \dfrac{250}{2n-1}$. $S_n$ is not, however, a series.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to find the partial sum $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^m \dfrac{250}{2n-1}$ and then consider its limit as $m\to \infty$.  You could try $$\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^m \dfrac{250}{2n-1} = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{2m} \dfrac{250}{n} - \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{m} \dfrac{250}{2n}=250H_{2m}-125 H_{m}$$

where $H_m=\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^m \dfrac{1}{n}\approx \log_e(m)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2m}$ is a [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).  So the partial sum will be about $125\log_e(m)+245.4$ which slowly increases without limit as $m$ increases.